# Java null pointer Exception in intelij idea

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmTbv.png)
I am trying to get the input from user by using System.console. However, I get a NullPointerException when I run the following code (I am trying to get input from the user).  import java.io.*; public class Systemlearn {     public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {         Console c

Comment: This is a known problem when launching from IntelliJ IDEA. Some hints on how you could solve it are in the linked duplicate, but according to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18814 the situation won't change in the near future.